# MongoDB incremental backup using mongodump of all collections

Tags: mongodb

I have a quite large mongodb community edition database (100 GB nd expected to grow).

Currently I am using mongodump twice a day for the backup. As the dump file is quite large (even in archive/gz format), and I am required to keep them several days back, I'd like to reduce the overall size using incremental backup.

I saw some posts regarding dumping the oplog and replaying it, but my plan is different, and I wonder if it is correct.
This is the plan:
Take a base full mongodump **once a week** , say on Saturday at 8:00 AM, using this command:

```
mongodump  --db ${DB_NAME} ${AUTH_PARAM}  --gzip --archive=${DB_BACKUP_PATH}/${TODAY}/db.archive
```

Then for each successive day until Friday, at 8:00 AM of each day, run mongodump based on --query, which will take the data only for that day for the last 24 hours (since 8:00 of the last day):

```
for COLL_NAME in $(cat /tmp/colls.txt)
do
  mongodump  --db octopusdb ${AUTH_PARAM} --collection $COLL_NAME $auth_string --query '$query_string' --gzip --archive=${output_dir}/mydb_audit.archive.$COLL_NAME"
done
```

where "$query_string" in the command above specifies the range datetime for the last 24 hours

If I need to restore, I will first restore the base dump from Saturday, and then restore each dump of each day till Friday (or whatever day is needed for the restore).

Does that plan cover the restore as required? Does it have any flaws?

Comment: How will you tell what's been deleted?

Comment: yes, you are probably right. I need to use the oplog where all is recorded by timestamp